# No output hebrew XeLaTeX

Tags: hebrew

Here is MWE:
I have MacOS with Monterey and TeXLive 2020

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt ]{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Lucida Grande}
\newfontfamily{\He}{Corsiva Hebrew}
\usepackage{bidi}

\begin{document}
\RL{יהוה}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You probably first need to select the newly defined font before the Hebrew part in the document body.

Comment: you have specified the font \newfontfamily{\He} but not used `\He` anywhere your log file is presumably showing warnings that the Lucida font does not have those characters

Comment: On my machine (MacOS,TexLive2020) it does work and produce a correct PDF, as long as I compile with XeLatex (and not Latex).  In any case, from my past experience with Hebrew writing in tex, I'd recommend using the polyglossia package.

Comment: My problem remains

Comment: I'd bet it is an installation problem. Maybe fonts are not installed? maybe liveTex needs an update? Is there any hint in the logs?

Answer (score 2):

here's a MWE with XeLatex/Polyglossia

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Times New Roman} 
\setsansfont{Arial}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew} 
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}

שלום, זהו ניסיון

קטע עברי משולב עם \RL{english} באמצע משפט

\begin{english}
A L-to-R paragraph with some \RL{עיברית} in the middle
\end{english}

\end{document}
```

which gives the pdf
[image: pdf file]  (if it doesn't show, see [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbuue.jpg))